# How to refresh checkout page before place order in woocomerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have plugin to calculate delivery in woocomerce. No I don't know how to edit "Place order" button in checkout page. I would like to add simple fuction to refresh chechout before submit order to validate.

I found simple function to do that in JavaScript

```
    jQuery( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
```

But i can't find where to edit "Place order" button in woocomerce plugin.
Any advices will be very good. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the condition for triggering. if it calls on every click how someone can place an order?

Comment: Yup. Trigger (update checkout) should run on every click button "Place Order"

Comment: by default its triggering update checkout once before placing order-shipping calculator by default triggers when you change the country/state/zip